# Is this equivalence of the compactness theorem true?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, model-theory

In my mathematical logic class the teacher asked us the following question: ¿is the compactness theorem equivalent to: let $\Gamma$ be a set of propositional formulas, and let $\sigma$ be a formula. If $\Gamma \models \sigma$  then there is finite ${ \Gamma  }_{ 0 }\subseteq \Gamma $ such that ${ \Gamma  }_{ 0 }\models \sigma $?, I have tried several times but can't find the correct way to prove it, I appreciate any help.

The statement my teacher gave was: $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable if and only if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

Comment: That's usually how the compactness theorem is stated; how is your teacher phrasing the compactness theorem?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I would guess: if $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable, then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. But yes Kira 1998, you should edit the question to clarify the statement of the compactness theorem you're working from.

Comment: Done, already edit the question.

Comment: For one direction, use $\sigma = \bot.$ For the other direction, use the fact that $\Gamma\models\sigma$ means $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot \sigma\}$ is unsatisfiable.

Comment: If it is equivalent to the compactness theorem, which is true, then it is also true. If it is not true, it is not equivalent to the compactness theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the two statements below are equivalent. Let us prove it. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of formulas.

1. For any  formula $\sigma$,  $\Gamma \models \sigma$  if and only if there is a finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma $ such that $\Gamma_0 \models \sigma $;
2. $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable if and only if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

*Proof that 1. implies 2.* We suppose that 1. holds and we prove that the equivalence in 2. holds

- $\Rightarrow$: Assume that $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable. Then, for every finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$, there is a structure that satisfies $\Gamma_0$. Let $\sigma$ be a contradiction formula (i.e. a formula that is not satisfied by any structure, for instance $\bot$ or $\alpha \land \lnot \alpha$). So, for every finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$, there is a structure that satisfies $\Gamma_0$ and not $\sigma$, i.e. $\Gamma_0 \not\models \sigma$.
  By 1. (direction left-to-right), $\Gamma \not\models \sigma$ and hence there exists a structure that satisfies $\Gamma$ but not $ \sigma$.
  In particular, $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.
- $\Leftarrow$:  Assume that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. Then, there exists a structure that satisfies all the formulas in $\Gamma$. In particular, it satisfies every finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$. Therefore, $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable. (Note that here we do not use the hypothesis that 1. holds)

*Proof that 2. implies 1.* We suppose that 2. holds and we prove that the equivalence in 1. holds. Let $\sigma$ be a formula.

- $\Rightarrow$: Assume that $\Gamma \models \sigma$. Then, every structure that satisfies $\Gamma$ does not satisfies $\lnot \sigma$, i.e. $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ is unsatisfiable. By 2. (direction left-to-right), $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ is not finitely satisfiable, hence there is a finite $\Gamma_0 \cup \{\lnot \sigma\} \subseteq \Gamma \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ that is unsatisfiable. Therefore, for some  finite $\Gamma_0 \cup \{\lnot \sigma\} \subseteq \Gamma \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$, every structure that satisfies $\Gamma_0$ satisfies $\sigma$ too, i.e. $\Gamma_0 \models \sigma$.
- $\Leftarrow$: Assume that $\Gamma_0 \models \sigma$ for some finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$. Then,  every structure that satisfies $\Gamma$ in particular satisfies $\Gamma_0$ and hence $\sigma$, since $\Gamma_0 \models \sigma$. Therefore, $\Gamma \models \sigma$. (Note that here we do not use the hypothesis that 2. holds)

---

In both statements 1. and 2., the interesting part is the left-to right direction. Indeed, in statement 1., the right-to-left direction is trivial and holds independently from the hypothesis that 2. holds.  And similarly, in statement 2., the right-to-left direction is trivial and holds independently from the hypothesis that 1. holds.

The left-to-right direction of the compactness theorem (in both formulations 1. and 2.) has the following logical form, at the meta-level:
$$\tag{*}\forall \exists \implies \exists \forall$$
What do I mean? Take the left-to-right direction of statement 2. By making explicit the meaning of "satisfiable" and "finitely satisfiable", it says: if *for all* finite subsets of $\Gamma$ *there exists* a structure that satisfies it, then *there is* a structure that satisfies *all* formulas in $\Gamma$. This is surprinsing, because $\Gamma$ can be an *infinite* set of formulas and so compactness theorem says that we can somehow transfer a property (satisfiability) from finite to infinite.

Usually, implications of the form $(*)$ does not hold. Think of natural numbers: the fact that for every natural number $n$ there is a natural number  greater than  $n$, does not imply that there is a natural number  greater all other natural numbers.
Compactness theorem says that when we talk about satisfiability of sets of formulas, the implication $(*)$ holds, even when the set $\Gamma$ of formulas is infinite.

The other direction (the right-to-left one) is of the form
$$\exists \forall \implies \forall \exists$$
which is obvious and indeed it corresponds to the less interesting part of statements 1. and 2.

Comment: The first bullet point of your proof doesn't make any sense to me. I think something got confused there.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - Thank you for your comment. What is unclear exactly in my proof?

Comment: You have $\sigma$ valid and $\Gamma_0$ satisfiable, and then you conclude $\Gamma_0\not\models \sigma$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco do you agree with what Alex says  ?

Comment: @AlexKruckman - Yes, you're right. Thank you for your remark. I should stop posting answers when I'm working, I lose track of what I'm doing and I write an abstract nonsense. Now I fixed it.

Comment: @Kira1998 - Yes, everything is fixed now. Thank you for your interest. Sorry, I wrote my answer when I was working, I lost track of what I was doing and I wrote an abstract nonsense. I've written now what I intended, and it makes sense, definitely.

Answer (score 3):

The version of Compactness you're given is: Γ is finitely satisfiable if and only if Γ is satisfiable. Then:

=> Let Γ be a set of propositional formulas, and let σ be any formula s.t. $Γ \models σ$. Consider the set $Σ = Γ \cup \{¬σ\}$. Clearly this is unsatisfiable, as any model of Γ must satisfy σ, so Γ and ¬σ cannot be satisfied simultaneously. It follows from our assumption that Σ is not finitely satisfiable, so $\exists Σ_0 \subseteq Σ$ finite which is unsatisfiable. Let $Γ_0 = Σ_0 \setminus \{¬σ\}$. We can then see that $Γ_0 \models σ$.

<= Clearly if Γ is satisfiable then it is finitely satisfiable. Suppose that Γ is finitely satisfiable. If Γ is empty then we're done. Otherwise, assume for a contradiction that Γ is not satisfiable, and let $σ \in Γ$. Since Γ is unsatisfiable, we see that $ Γ \setminus \{σ\} \models ¬σ$. By our assumption, we have that $\exists Γ_0 \subseteq Γ \setminus \{σ\}$ finite, such that $Γ_0 \models ¬σ$. We then have that $Γ_0 \cup \{σ\}$ is a finite subset of Γ, which is unsatisfiable. This contradicts our hypothesis, so Γ must be satisfiable.

Comment: +1.  For the second direction, it's a bit cleaner to take $\sigma$ to be $\top$ (or some tautology), rather than removing an element from $\Gamma$.